# How to return callback json from VC Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I am using 3rd party Kendo UI in client side. it expects data from server in below format.

```
        callback([{"TaskID":4,"OwnerID":2,"Title":"Bowling}])
```

I am having below code in server side

```
    public JsonResult GetAllAppointments()
    {
        IEnumerable<AppointmentModel> appointmentCollection = app_repository.GetAll();
        if (appointmentCollection == null)
        {
            return Json(appointmentCollection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(appointmentCollection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

But this returns just json, how to add "callback" to it?

Comment: If you return a `JSON` it should be a valid `JSON`. I think you have to think about another method to add a String or StringBuffer to your valid JSON. But if the UI also expect a valid JSON format, you cant return `callback([{"TaskID":4,"OwnerID":2,"Title":"Bowling}])` because this is not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should get an interceptor at client side which should let you modify your response format..but since you have not provided any further details I won't be able to comment on that.

You can change your return type fron JsonResult to string and manually serialize your response.You can use Json.NET to serialize your response.

Here is a [NuGet LINK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) for the same.

```
public class AppointmentModel
    {
        public string TaskID { get; set; }
        public string OwnerID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public string GetAllAppointments()
    {
        string responseFormat = @"callback({0})";

        IEnumerable<AppointmentModel> appointmentCollection = getDummyAppoitments();
        if (appointmentCollection != null)
        {
            string json_string = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appointmentCollection);

            return string.Format(responseFormat, json_string);;
        }

        //no items were present so sending empty response;
        return string.Format(responseFormat, "[]");;
    }

    private IEnumerable<AppointmentModel> getDummyAppoitments()
    {
        return new List<AppointmentModel>() { 
            new AppointmentModel()
            {
                TaskID = "4",
                OwnerID = "2",
                Title = "Bowling"
            }
        };
    }
```

Check out response.

[image]

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks sameer, can u help here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479836/how-to-prevent-kendo-ui-shceduler-event-popup-and-show-it-in-same-page